# Migrating Access database to sharepoint

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

My agency uses Access databases on a shared drive. The data sources we use are imported text and excel files. We will no longer have access to the shared drive and have been told to migrate our data to sharepoint. From what I have read we should not store the databases on sharepoint.

Our tables are too large for sharepoint lists. Also, I don't know how we would continue to run the queries and reports we have in the databases. Some of the tables are created by queries that link several databases and tables- we run macros to get the reports.

We do not have access to SQL server at the moment. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: We can't help you with this. If you're told to migrate something to SharePoint but it doesn't fit on SharePoint, you need to be talking to the person that told you to do something impossible, not random internet strangers.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The tables as they are exceed the capacity for sharepoint lists, but if we export them to text or excel files they will be fine. My concern is how to then be able to continue to update and use that data in the same way that were able to using access.

Comment: Yeah, not at all. SharePoint is not a database, you can use lists and pretend it is, but if you upload your tables as Excel files or text files you either stop early on because it's not working or create an unusable abomination. The only way to query these is to download them, then query them locally, and overhead will be massive if they're truly too large for lists.

Comment: Thank your for affirming this. I keep researching and to find a way to make it work but it seems that even if I can make it functional it will be a mess. we are trying to convince them to allow us access to SQL server. Thank you so much for your time!!

Comment: Agree with the above. I would also concur that this site shouldn't be the place to discuss this. As per the Help Center, rule six, this question is off-topic. For reference, "Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools."

Comment: One of the main issues is the ability to run queries, so I disagree.